# Allow map to accept int, bool and string as values

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I created a map so I could use it like a dictionary in python. My problem is that I would like alpha to accept not only int, but also bool or string. so alpha could be true/false or "chad". I understand std::string, int is restponsible for it, but I can't figure out how to accept multiple values. (or any)

```
std::map<std::string, int> mymap = {
              { "alpha", 0 },
              { "beta", 0 },
              { "gamma", 0 } };
```

Comment: Use union. If had access to C++17 use std::variant or std::any

Comment: @Oblivion `std::string` won't work well in a `union`.